# How I can store in keys and values in a dictionary when iterating?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

I have a list like this:

```
my_list = ['@F1', 'OBCD', '!', '@F2', 'ADDAB', '!', '@F3', 'OKKA', '!']
```

I want it to become a dictionary like this:

```
{'@F1': 'OBCD', '@F2': 'ADDAB', '@F3': 'OKKA'}
```

However I'm stuck on this:

```
my_dict = {}
for i in my_list:
    if i[0] != '@' and i[0].isalpha() == False:
        #pass
    else:
        my_dict[i] = my_list.next(i)
```

I know the .next(i) doesn't work but I'm basically trying to say "get that i that comes after.

If someone has a solution, could you please keep it iterative and elaborate, because I get lost with those very concatenated responses that have a bunch of stuff going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `enumerate()`. This will return the items as well as indexes. It iterates through the list, uf it sees `@` in that item it will store the next item with that  string as index.

So your code will look like this -

```
my_list = ['@F1', 'OBCD', '!', '@F2', 'ADDAB', '!', '@F3', 'OKKA', '!']

# expected: {'@F1': 'OBCD', '@F2': 'ADDAB', '@F3': 'OKKA'}
my_dict = {}

for indx, item in enumerate(my_list):
    if '@' in item:
        my_dict[item] = my_list[indx+1]

print(my_dict)
```

Result

```
{'@F1': 'OBCD', '@F2': 'ADDAB', '@F3': 'OKKA'}
```

If you want to be as sure that the index string has to start with `@` then

```
for indx, item in enumerate(my_list):
    if item[0] == '@':
        my_dict[item] = my_list[indx+1]
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding!

Comment: This is not right. What if the list was like this: *['@F1', 'O@CD', '!', '@F2', 'ADDAB', '!', '@F3', 'OKKA', '!']* or *['@F1', '@OCD', '!', '@F2', 'ADDAB', '!', '@F3', 'OKKA', '!']*

Comment: We can also make it more complex and better. If we start looking for `f"@F{i}"`. But he said he has a list like that and this might have worked for him. 
Like there is no perfect technology, no code is perfect either.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate()` to generate the indexes to allow you to access the 'next' item in the list:

```py
my_list = ['@F1', 'OBCD', '!', '@F2', 'ADDAB', '!', '@F3', 'OKKA', '!']

my_dict = {}
for idx,item in enumerate(my_list):
    if item[0] == '@':
        my_dict[item] = my_list[idx+1]

print(my_dict)
```

Output as requested.

Note that this relies on your current format of '@' denoting the key and there always being another element to be the value.

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that you don't have to check explicitly for '!' because the list data are in groups of 3. Therefore:

```
my_list = ['@F1', 'OBCD', '!', '@F2', 'ADDAB', '!', '@F3', 'OKKA', '!']

my_dict = {my_list[i]: my_list[i+1] for i in range(0, len(my_list), 3)}

print(my_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
{'@F1': 'OBCD', '@F2': 'ADDAB', '@F3': 'OKKA'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it with `next`.

```py
def make_dict(lst):
    it = iter(lst)           # Note 1
    d = {}
    for k in it:             # Note 2
        if k[0] == '@':
            d[k] = next(it)  # Notes 3, 4
        elif k != '!':       # Note 5 
            raise ValueError(f"Expected '!' but received {k}")
    return d
```

#### Explanatory Notes:

1. In order to use `next`, you need an actual iterator, not just an object which can be iterated (like a list). To get an iterator from an iterable, you use the `iter` built-in function.
2. Once you have an iterator, you can use it in a `for` statement just like an iterable. In fact, the implementation of `for` creates an iterator from a iterable, so you only need to do it yourself if you have some extra need. (If you -- or the `for` loop -- call `iter` on an iterator, it returns the iterator itself.)
3. Calling `next` on an iterator returns the next value and advances the iterator. Since the `for` loop is using the same iterator, it won't see the value extracted with the explicit call to `next`.
4. If there is no next element (which would be an input error), `next` will raise `StopIteration`, but that will not cause the `for` loop to quietly terminate; that only happens if `StopIteration` is raised while the `for` loop is trying to get the next value. `StopIteration` is not a very useful error indication; it would probably be better to catch the exception with a `try` statement and throw a more meaningful exception. I didn't do that because it's a bit of a distraction, but...
5. This code does attempt to raise a meaningful exception if there is something other than `!` following a key/value pair. You might be happy to just discard the extra item without producing an error message (depending on your expected input), in which case you could just remove the `elif` and following statement.

#### Appendix: a non-iterative solution, even though it was explicitly unrequested:

```py
d = { k: next(it) for it in [iter(my_list)] for k in it if k[0] == '@' }
```